# PHP: Adding to array replaces previous value

Tags: php, arrays, database, replace

**What I'm trying to do:**
Pull data from a database and insert it into an array

**The code I'm using:**

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `products`, categories WHERE category = cat_ID AND pro_ID = " . $_GET['id'];
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name = $row['pro_name'];
            $cartContents[$name] = array(
                "id" => $row['pro_ID'],
                "name" => $row['pro_name'],
                "price" => $row['price'],
                "quantity" => $_GET['q']
            );
        }
```

**The problem:**
This does indeed take the values from the database and insert them into the array, but it replaces everything dat was in the array before this.

**What I've tried:**
- Replacing `array(...)` with `[...]`
- Using the following code:

```
$cartContents[$name]["id"] = $row['pro_ID'];
$cartContents[$name]["name"] = $row['pro_name'];
$cartContents[$name]["price"] = $row['price'];
$cartContents[$name]["quantity"] = $_GET['q'];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Where do you create the array `$cartContents` ?

Comment: well, yeah, if `$cartContents['foo']` existed beforehand and your query retrieves `'foo'`, you'll replace the original values with whatever the query returned.

Comment: What was in the array before? Was there anything with the same key($name) ?

Comment: No, the value that was already in the array, had a different key. And the array is created somewhere in the beginning of the code

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the data to be replaced for the `$cartContents[$name]` just update your code like this;

```
$cartContents[$name][] = array(
    "id" => $row['pro_ID'],
    "name" => $row['pro_name'],
    "price" => $row['price'],
    "quantity" => $_GET['q']
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. It still replaces previous values

Comment: Can you please provide the structure of the array so I can provide an accurate answer?

Comment: Before: `Array ( [Naam] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Naam [price] => 3 [quantity] => 2 ) ) ) `  
After trying to add `[Name]`: `Array ( [Name] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Name [price] => 4 [quantity] => 2 ) ) ) `.  
 What I want it to be: `Array (
 [Naam] => Array (
  [id] => 2
  [name] => Naam
  [price] => 3
  [quantity] => 2
 )
 [Name] => Array (
  [id] => 1
  [name] => Name
  [price] => 4
  [quantity] => 2
 )
) `

Comment: Ok, try doing it this way; 
`$i = count($cartContents[$name]) - 1;`
then use it inside the `while` like this
    `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cartContents[$name][$i] = array(
    "id" => $row['pro_ID'],
    "name" => $row['pro_name'],
    "price" => $row['price'],
    "quantity" => $_GET['q']
);
$i++;
}`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that would work. Before running this code, there is no `$name` key in `$cartContents`

Comment: What I'm trying to explain to you is that you can take the count of the [Naam] (as provided in the array structure) `$i = count($array[Naam]) - 1;` to get the last index of it then increment it in `while` put the $i++ at the beginning of `while` and you should be good to go.

Comment: That didn't work. It did indeed add the new item to the array, but it still replaces previous content